# Can I initialize a class with a variable which is defined by a function inside that class in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, class, initializer

Is it possible that the variable which initializes my class is computed by a function inside that class?

I first initialize MyClass:

```
let MyClass = MyClass()
```

Second, this would be the code in the class:

```
class MyClass {
    var myString = computeRandomString()

    func computeRandomString() -> String {
        piece of code
        return(randomString)
    }
}
```

Whenever I create an instance of MyClass I want the myString to be a randomString. In order for that I made a function within the same class.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.

First, if `computeRandomString` does not rely on knowing about anything about specific instances of this class, it could be converted to a class function, or simply moved outside of the class entirely.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    var myString = MyClass.computeRandomString()

    class func computeRandomString() -> String {
        return "random string"
    }
}
```

or

```
func computeRandomString() -> String {
    return "random string"
}

class MyClass {
    var myString = computeRandomString()
}
```

---

The second option is to set it in the initializers (rather than giving it a default value), but you'll only be able to do this after *all* values (including this one) have been assigned a value.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    var myString: String

    init() {
        myString = ""
        myString = computeRandomString()
    }

    func computeRandomString() -> String {
        return "random string"
    }
}
```

---

The reason we can't use an instance method to assign a default value for an instance variable is better explained by the warning generated when we try to use the instance method within an initializer before first giving it a value:

```
class MyClass {
    var myString: String

    init() {
        myString = computeRandomString()
    }

    func computeRandomString() -> String {
        return "random string"
    }
}
```

On the `myString =`... line in `init`, we see the following error:

> Use of 'self' in method call 'computeRandomString' before all stored properties are initialized.

This error, unfortunately, does not show up when we use it as the property's default value, as you're trying to do, but it does accurately describe the actual problem.

We cannot use `self` before our class is fully initialized, and that includes calling methods on `self`.  And until all of our stored properties have valid values, our instance is not fully initialized, so we can never use an instance method to give a non-optional stored property its first value.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is a lazy computed property.
The string is created when the property is accessed the first time

```
class MyClass {

  lazy var computeRandomString : String = {
    let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789"
    let alphaLength = UInt32(alphabet.characters.count)
    var randomString : String = ""
    for _ in 0..<20 {
      let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(alphaLength))
      let index = alphabet.startIndex.advancedBy(random)
      randomString += String(alphabet[index])
    }
     return randomString
  }()
}

for _ in 0..<10 {
  print(MyClass().computeRandomString)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to do it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    var myString: String

    init() {
        self.myString = MyClass.computeRandomString()
    }

    static func computeRandomString() -> String {
        piece of code
        return(randomString)
    }
}
```

This will set `myString` to the results of `computeRandomString()` on initialisation (creating) of a `MyClass`-object.

I changed `computeRandomString()` to static because otherwise it could not be used before initialisation has finished, thanks to @nhgrif.

Comment: This won't compile (even if the code in `computeRandomString` is valid, compilable code).  You can't do this in `init` like that.

Comment: Is that because `computeRandomString()` cannot be used because the object is not initialised yet?